# How do I prevent from a symbol at part title to be in a new line

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{adforn}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{ #2 #3\adforn{64}}
\begin{document}
\part{ABC}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image]

I want the leaf will be at the same line of the part name, if it's possible, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: `\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{ #2 \mbox{#3\adforn{64}}}` (or with `\mbox` replaced by another box like `\hbox`)?

Comment: @marmot Upvoted :)

Comment: @JouleV Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I describe here is a sort of workaround. The line does not break without a reason. In principle you should look into what `\partlineswithprefixformat` does and why it produces such a narrow box. I am now assuming that you do not want to do any of this, but just force the leaf to be in the same line as ABC. (There can be reasons for this, e.g. when a journal "blessed" you with a murky document class. Clearly, `scrartcl` is not murky. But the following will most likely work for murky templates, too.) Then you could do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{adforn}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{ #2 \hbox{#3\adforn{64}}}
\begin{document}
\part{ABC}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another workaround assuming there is no `\strut` command in the part title. It works also with part titles longer than one line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{adforn}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{#2%
  {\xapptocmd\strut{\adforn{64}}{}{\PatchFailed}#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\part{ABC}
\part{ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]